# how to show only the pictures in the home page's posts

Tags: html, css

how to show only the pictures in the home page's posts without any text for my website www.turkish-learn.com

I need to show only the headline with image and read more button

Answer (score 0):

try the CSS code below

```
 .post-body.entry-content div div {
        display: none;
    }
    .nbtentry-meta, .nbtentry-meta a, .pingback .edit-link {
        display: none;
    }
```